# Is it necessary the object of 近づける movable?

Tags: grammar

Assume that there is a pond in the garden in which a boy is playing around with his father.

What is the correct expression that his mother must use?

- A: 息子を池に近づけるな！ Keep away the son from the pond.
- B: 池を息子に近づけるな！ Keep away the pond from the son.

My feeling says that I have to use A because the object of 近づける must be movable. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is perfectly correct. You have to say A because Sentence B sounds like 池 is a movable object.

Well, this is off-topic, but addressing one's son as 息子 is weird. [See this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8204/5010).